# On Ramanujan's beautiful cubic identity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, combinatorial-identities, q-identities

Let $a_i, b_i, c_i$ be defined by the following$\colon$

$\frac{1 + 53X + 9X^2}{1 - 82X - 82X^2 + X^3} = a_0 + a_1X + \ldots$.

$\frac{2 - 26X - 12X^2}{1 - 82X - 82X^2 + X^3} = b_0 + b_1X + \ldots$.

$\frac{2 + 8X + 10X^2}{1 - 82X - 82X^2 + X^3} = c_0 + c_1X + \ldots$.

Then the following result is known$\colon$

> **Theorem.** (Ramanujan). $a_n^3 + b_n^3 = c_n^3 + (-1)^n$ holds.

My question is

> How did Ramanujan prove this?

Comment: I believe it would be more informative to add explanations of how does your question relate to Galois representations, combinatorics and $q$-identities, since you use these tags.

Comment: @nfdc23 Yes, that was a typo. Using https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%241-82X-82X%5E2%2BX%5E3&p=1, I found Ramanujan's identity mentioned here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansSumIdentity.html and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381111/generalizing-ramanujans-sum-of-cubes-identity, where there is more useful info. That should answer your question, except that nobody knows how Ramanujan himself obtained (and *sometimes* proved) his breathtaking results.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002280/1729-fermats-last-theorem-and-ramanujans-sums-of-cubes-formula/2002425?s=2|0.0000#2002425, where it is actually answered.

Comment: You ask "how did Ramanujan prove this?", but maybe the first thing to ask is "DID Ramanujan prove this?" (as opposed to *finding* it in some other way, e.g., intuition). It's probably hard to answer since Ramanujan doesn't seem to have left a discussion in his notebooks, but there is a commentary on this identity (including a proof that would have been accessible to Ramanujan) in Yogananada, "A Cube as (Almost) a Sum of Two Cubes (A Remarkable Identity of S. Ramanujan)" (2012), doi:10.1007/s12045-012-0095-7 (referencing further work by Hirschhorn)

Comment: This should be a comment, but I do not have the reputation. I was recently at a talk and dinner with Ken Ono at Mount Holyoke College. He mentioned that he had seen this in Ramanujan's notebooks and that they were computations regarding near-misses to Fermat's last theorem.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know how Ramanujan proved this, but to *prove* such a thing is not really a big deal. Say, $a_n$ is a linear combination of $p_i^n$, where $(1-p_1x)(1-p_2x)(1-p_3x)=1-82x-82x^2+x^3$. Thus $a_n^3$ is a linear combination of $p_i^{3n}$, $(p_i^2p_j)^n$, $(p_1p_2p_3)^n=(-1)^n$. The same for $b_n^3$ and $c_n^3$ and $(-1)^n$. The space of such sequences has dimension 11 and each such a sequence is uniquely determined by the first 11 terms. So, it suffices to check the equality for $n=0,1,\dots,10$.

Comment: From what you wrote, we can find the generating function of $a_n^3$, and check the equality of the generating functions for $a_n^3,b_n^3, c_n^3, (-1)^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is alternative approach.

Comment: $a_{10}^3 = 15831762468519533452047880726112553970057692205816746242041$. I would be surprised if Ramanujan expanded the three fractions up to order 10, just because. There must be some other reason.